# How fill data in mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i write a function to fill content in my database but show some error , i use below function to fill data

```
function fillData($con,$dbName,$tableName,$arr){
$columns = implode(", ",array_keys($arr));
$escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($arr));
$values  = implode(", ", $escaped_values);
$sql = "INSERT INTO ". $tableName ." ($columns) VALUES ($values)";
$myfilling=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    if($myfilling){

        echo "\n  data succsess add to table";

    }else{ 
        echo "\n Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($con);
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

but return error

```
 Error creating table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'M, 1392/12/28, 12:30:08, 3.99 M, 10 B, 10%, 493, 17.63, 17.60, ┘à╪ش╪د╪▓' at line 1
```

what's wrong in my code is depend to $values string type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put single quotes around values. You can achieve this when imploding like:

```
$values  = "'" . implode("', '", $escaped_values) .  "'";
```

Comment: thanx alot .. it fix ... but show's below error

 Error creating table: Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 8126. You have to hange some columns to TEXT or
 BLOBs

Comment: You need to replace VARCHAR(XXXX) fields to TEXT if XXXX is too large.

Comment: Then it seems there are too many rows as varchar(255). Converting all of them to TEXT would not be a good choice. You can try limiting the number of columns

Comment: yes it's ... what number of varchar(255) is allow ?

Comment: To answer this question requires some computation with the numbers given in documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html. I suggest trying a reasonable number like 10/20...?